# Are there any advantages to using Apollo Server's dataSources config option?

Tags: javascript, typescript, graphql, apollo, apollo-server

Following the [Apollo Server docs on dataSources](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/features/data-sources/#accessing-data-sources-from-resolvers), one would assume that the best way to access data in a GraphQL resolver would be through the `dataSources` option on the server config.

However, the app I'm working on has requirements that result in many different data source classes (truncated into `...` in my *handler.ts* file below, but there are about 10 now and there will be many more in the future). This means that every data source class will be instantiated for each query/mutation the server receives, which I'm thinking could eventually result in a bit of latency if I have enough data source classes.

I'm thinking of not using the `dataSources` option and instead just instantiating each data source class as necessary by using the resolver context to call the `initialize()` method on the Apollo `RESTDataSource` class (sample resolver method pasted below), which seems to provide all the same functionality to the data source class that the `dataSources` config option does.

I'm wondering:

- Are there any benefits / disadvantages of using the `dataSources` option that I'm not aware of?
- Why would the Apollo docs encourage you to instantiate all data source classes for each request?

Thanks in advance for any insight you may have!

**Server config from *handler.ts*:**

```
const server = new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers,
  introspection: true,
  playground: true,
  dataSources: (): IDataSources => {
    return {
      entity: new Entity(),
      notes: new Notes(), // this could be removed if "new" resolver method is used
      ... // like 8 more data sources go here
    };
  },
  context: ({
    event,
    context
  }: {
    event: APIGatewayEvent;
    context: Context;
  }): IGraphqlServerOptionContext => {
    const user = new User(event);
    return { apiGatewayEvent: event, apiGatewayContext: context, user };
  },
  extensions: [() => new LogFunctionExtension()]
});
```

**Sample (alternative) resolver method from *resolvers.ts*:**

```
export const resolvers: IResolvers<any, IResolverContext> = {
  Query: {
    getNotes: async (
      _source,
      args: QueryGetNotesArgs,
      resolverContext: IResolverContext
    ) => {
      validateRequestHeaders('common', resolverContext.apiGatewayEvent);
      // old method of accessing notes data source class:
      // const {
      //   dataSources: { notes }
      // } = resolverContext;

      // new method of accessing notes data source class:
      const notes = new Notes(resolverContext);

      return notes.getNoteDetails(args);
    },
  }
};
```

**new Notes data source class constructor:**

```
export default class Notes extends RESTDataSource<IDataSourceContext> {
  constructor(inputContext: IDataSourceContext) {
    this.initialize({
      context: inputContext,
      cache: new InMemoryLRUCache()
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Here you're initializing a separate data source *per resolver* and creating a new `InMemoryLRUCache` instance every time. When Apollo calls `initialize`, it uses the same instance that's shared by all datasources. Source [here](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-server/blob/master/packages/apollo-server-core/src/requestPipeline.ts). Under your current approach, you won't be able to take advantage of caching.

Comment: @DanielRearden thanks for the insight. Couldn't I just create and export a cache in the _handler.ts_ file, and then either provide that cache to the server config or just reference that cache in each data source class constructor?

Comment: @DanielRearden or to put that another way, does the `dataSources` option provide any benefits _aside_ from automatically passing the context and cache?

Comment: You probably want a per-request cache, otherwise you'll end up returning stale data. I'm not familiar enough with the source code to provide an educated answer, which is why I commented instead of posting one :) I suspect if the docs explicitly tell you to do it that way, there may be a good reason for it. Also note, even with a 100 DataSources, you're only initializing some objects, not actually making any requests so I don't think you'll see a noticeable difference in performance.